# WPF splash screen with System.Threading.Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

The following C# and Windows Forms code is taken from this YouTube video: *[C# Tutorial - Splash Screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ4BkPyZllY)*

```
namespace SplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartForm));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            InitializeComponent();
            t.Abort();
        }

        public void StartForm()
        {
            Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert the above code to VB.NET and WPF code.

The following code shows what I have done so far;

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded( _
      sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
      Handles Me.Loaded

        Dim t As System.Threading.Thread = _
          New System.Threading.Thread( _
            New System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartForm))
        t.Start()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        t.Abort()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartForm()
        Dim mySplashScreenWindow As New SplashScreenWindow()
        mySplashScreenWindow.Owner = Me
        mySplashScreenWindow.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

> Delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

So, how can I solve that error?

Comment: Can you show the error as text?

Comment: I'm going to update this for you and add the Error Text. In the future, please don't use images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btky721f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), you can see from point 2 that:

> Create an instance of the thread with the appropriate delegate for the starting point of the thread. Use the **AddressOf** operator to create the delegate in Visual Basic

Which explains the error that you got:

> Delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

It is missing in your code, so what you should do is add it before the `StartForm` function in the constructor, such as:

```
Dim t As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartForm))
t.Start()
```

Comment: This is not your intended question, and to follow SO rules, this is a whole new question that you should post. According to this question, this is the right answer I think.

Comment: @Markowitz Just because System.Threading.Thread is very old does not mean it is not good. The addition operator is even older, but there are still many uses for it.